# javascript createElement via appendChild returning error

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to write a short javascript function to add buttons for prev/next to a css-slider I've put together. 
I don't have access to the DOM, so figured I'd just insert the div's via javascript. Here is the function:

```
function createfn(){
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  var prev = document.createTextNode("<");
  element.appendChild(prev);
  document.getElementsByClassName("sqs-gallery")[0].appendChild(element);
}
window.onload=createfn();
```

I am getting an error:

> "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"

The `div` container with class `.sqs-gallery` is definitely appearing on the page. I was questioning whether this was somehow running before the DOM fully loaded, but I have the `window.onload` in there which (I believe) should wait until everything is loaded before running the function.

Any and all thoughts and help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As you've described the situation, it should work. Try adding a minimal reproducing example to your question.

Comment: Does an elements with class name `sqs-gallery` isset?

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses here: `window.onload=createfn()`

Comment: * What is the full error returned in console?
* Have you tried to console.log your variables and what's the results?

Answer (score 5):

You perform
`window.onload=createfn()`;

it means that you assign result of `createfn()` to `onload` (not the function). 
And function "`createfn`" being executed immediately (does not wait for window loading).

Just remove parentheses to assign handler instead of function value.

Comment: That did the trick! Figured it was a stupid mistake like that! Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the code as `window.onload=createfn()` (with the parenteheses) `createfn` will run directly as the code starts to run (even before the DOM has loaded) because the result needs to be assigned to `window.onload`.

What you instead should be trying to do is assign the function, not the result: `window.onload=createfn`. This should work just fine.